# Isn't NSPersistentStore thread safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am downloading json data from server, parsing it and storing it in to the database using CoreData. So next time when the view is loaded, it fetch the data using Core Data and along with that parsing and db insertion also happens. Before insertion, I am deleting the existent data also. Following is the flow that I am using:

- Checks for data in database.
- If available, fetch and render data in UI. And downloading data from server is also do along with fetching and rendering.
- Delete the existing data and insert again.

The above steps crashes the application some time. What is the best approach to handle this case?

What I felt, sometimes at the time of fetching, download completes and deletes data. It may be depends on the speed of fetching.

That's why I got the question in mind that NSPersistentStore is thread safe?

Can anyone help to understand what approach to follow in this case?

Sree.

Comment: No its not thread safe, [Reference](http://duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/). Post your crash report here, that will help in solving the issue

Comment: The NSManagedObjectContext is not thread safe. In your active scheme in XCode add the following launch argument: "-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1"  (without the quotes). It will immediately halt execution when you access the MOC from the wrong thread. Very convenient for debugging.

Comment: Be sure to test on an iOS8+ device when debugging Core Data threading